# Add a new column to a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to add a column to a csv file that combines strings from two other columns. Whenever I try this I either get an output csv with only the new column or an output with all of the original data and not the new column.

This is what I have so far:

```
with open(filename) as csvin:
    readfile = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter=',')
    with open(output, 'w') as csvout:
        writefile = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in readfile:
            result = [str(row[10]) + ' ' + str(row[11])]
            writefile.writerow(result)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[str(row[10]) + ' ' + str(row[11])]` would only be one column - you don't attempt to write anything else to the row and there is no comma delimiter. Are you trying to combine `row[10]` and `row[11]` into a single value that should be in its own column, in addition to the existing columns?

Comment: Yes I am trying to combine rows 10 and 11 into one column, and add that column onto the existing csv.

Comment: @glayne but you don't add it to `row`: `writefile.writerow(row + result)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No input to test, but try this. Your current approach doesn't include the existing data for each row that already exists in your input data. `extend` will take the list that represents each row and then add another item to that list... equivalent to adding a column.

```
import csv
with open(filename) as csvin:
    readfile = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter=',')
    with open(output, 'w') as csvout:
        writefile = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in readfile:
            row.extend([str(row[10]) + ' ' + str(row[11])])
            writefile.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Is `row` a `list` or a `tuple`?

Comment: @PeterWood I had a mistake earlier, now corrected. But `csv.reader` should return a nested list, with each row a sub-list

Comment: It's a `list`: from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) *Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings*

Comment: You open output twice

Comment: @HaiVu well spotted. I started to convert the presented code to what I would normally do, then decided just to stick with initial. Thanks, I'll correct.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that glayne wants to combine column 10 and 11 into one.
In my approach, I concentrate on how to transform a single row first:

```
def transform_row(input_row):
    output_row = input_row[:]
    output_row[10:12] = [' '.join(output_row[10:12])]
    return output_row
```

Once tested to make sure that it works, I can move on to replace all rows:

```
with open('data.csv') as inf, open('out.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerows(transform_row(row) for row in reader)
```

Note that I use the `writerows()` method to write multiple rows in one statement.

Comment: I like this approach more than the others. It is easier to read and understand. The `transform_row()` function can become more generic by removing the hardcoded list slicing and adding the required arguments, thus making it a reusable tool.

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet combines strings in column 10 and column 11 in each row and add that to the end of the each row

```
import csv
input = 'test.csv'
output= 'output.csv'
with open(input, 'rb') as csvin:
    readfile = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter=',')
    with open(output, 'wb') as csvout:
        writefile = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in readfile:
            result = row + [row[10]+row[11]]
            writefile.writerow(result)
```