# Create a new csv file with a column from another csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to create a new csv file with only one column from another exsting csv file. Instead of printing Address in just one column in the csv file, Python is spreading the Address across multiple columns. What can I do to eradicate the multiple column issue.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import csv
from itertools import imap
from operator import itemgetter


def main():
    delimiter = ','
    with open('C:/Addresses.csv', 'rb') as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=delimiter)
        with open('thefirstcolumn.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
            writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=delimiter)
            writer.writerows(imap(itemgetter(1), reader))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the original file:

```
abcdcolumn      Address             
********-A-1    6525 Mountain   
********-A-2    6543 Mountain       
********-A-4    6579 Mountain   
********-A-5    6597 Mountain   
********-A-6    6615 Mountain       
********-A-7    6633 Mountain
```

The Result in the new csv file:

```
    A   d   d   r   e   s   s           
    6   5   2   5       M   o   u   n   t
    6   5   4   3       M   o   u   n   t
    6   5   6   1       M   o   u   n   t
    6   5   7   9       M   o   u   n   t
    6   5   9   7       M   o   u   n   t
    6   6   1   5       M   o   u   n   t
    6   6   3   3       M   o   u   n   t
```

Comment: can you show contents of the original file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new column to a csv file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733158/add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writer.writerows` expects a list of lists, you are feeding it a list of strings.

Changing `writer.writerows(imap(itemgetter(1), reader))` to something like:

```
for address in imap(itemgetter(1), reader):
      writer.writerow([address])
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

In general I'd use the pandas package for csv file manipulation.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv(input_file, delimiter=delimiter)
df['Address'].to_csv(output_file)
```